# Update a column with LastExclusionDate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

In SQL Server 2012, I have a table `t1` where we store a list of excluded product.

I would like to add a column `LastExclusionDate` to store the date since when the product has been excluded.

Every day the product is inserted into the table if it is excluded. If not there will be no row and the next time when the product will be excluded there will be a gap date with the previous insert.

I would like to find a T-SQL query to update the `LastExclusionDate` column.

I would like to use it to populate column `LastExclusionDate` the first time (=initialisation) and use it every day to update the column when we insert a new row

I've tried this query, but I don't know how to get `LastExclusionDate`!

```
;WITH Cte AS
(
    SELECT
        product_id,
        CreationDate,
        LAG(CreationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID ORDER BY CreationDate) AS GapStart,
        (DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(CreationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_id ORDER BY CreationDate), CreationDate) -1) AS GapDays
    FROM 
        #t1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Here's some sample data:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| product_id | CreationDate | LastExclusionDate_(toPopulate) |
+------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
|        100 | 2018-05-01   | 2018-05-01                     |
|        100 | 2018-05-02   | 2018-05-01                     |
|        100 | 2018-05-03   | 2018-05-01                     |
|        100 | 2018-06-01   | 2018-06-01                     |
|        100 | 2018-06-02   | 2018-06-01                     |
|        200 | 2018-09-01   | 2018-09-01                     |
|        200 | 2018-09-02   | 2018-09-01                     |
|        200 | 2018-09-17   | 2018-09-17                     |
+------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: I've tried this query to get gap date. But I don't know how to get LastExclusionDate !

Comment: Howdy @ema. Sorry for the unfriendly welcome there. Sheesh. This is a particularly difficult problem, so it's no wonder you are stuck on it. This is a problem known as "Islands and Gaps" where you have records with contiguous date ranges, then a gap, then more records with a continuous date range. I would highly suggest reading [this post "The SQL of Islands and Gaps"](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) which covers a lot of what you are facing. I'd offer an answer here, but my tsql in this area is rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ongoing daily insertions it can be done with something like this.

```
INSERT INTO <yourTable>
    SELECT 
        newProduct.[product_id],
        newProduct.[creationDate],
        isnull(existingProduct.[lastExclusionDate], newProduct.[creationDate]) AS [lastExclusionDate]
    FROM 
        (SELECT <@product_id> AS [product_id], <@createionDate> AS [creationDate]) AS newProduct 
    LEFT JOIN #temp existingProduct
        ON existingProduct.[product_id] = newProduct.product_id
        AND existingProduct.[creationDate] = DATEADD(DAY,-1,newProduct.[creationDate])
```

I've got a demo here http://rextester.com/BDEO23118 . It's a larger than necessary demo because it uses the code above with the data you provided to populate a table row-by-row like you might in a daily update process. It then does individual insertions using this code with some new dates so you can see the way it handles new ranges.  (just an FYI, rextester displays result dates in day.month.year hh:mm:ss format, but you can dump the script into management studio and it will output in DATE format)

Answer (score 2):

The idea in finding gap-less sequences is to compare the series to a gap-less sequence and find groups of records where the difference of both doesn't change. For example, when the date increases one by one and a row number also does, then the difference between both stays the same and we found a group:

```
WITH 
  cte (product_id, CreationDate, grp) AS (
    SELECT product_id, CreationDate
        , DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', CreationDate)
          - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY CreationDate)
    FROM #t1
  )
SELECT product_id, CreationDate
    , MIN(CreationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, grp) AS LastExclusionDate
FROM cte
```

Comment: great. A short and clever query. I will try to adust to my context Thx